# MySQL join across 3 tables running very slowly

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, inner-join

I'm displaying a page of diary events along with client details and the most recent note from their case.

I'm using Laravel's query builder and my query at the moment is:

```
$data['events'] = DB::table('events')
    ->where('cancelled', 0)
    ->where('complete', 0)
    ->join('clients', 'events.clientid', '=', 'clients.id')
    ->join('notes', function ($join) {
    $join->on('events.clientid', '=', 'notes.clientid')
    ->on('notes.created_at', '=', DB::raw('(select created_at from notes where clientid = clients.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)'));
        })
    ->select('events.*', 'clients.firstname', 'clients.surname', 'notes.note')
    ->orderBy('eventtime', 'asc')->paginate(75); //Load events sorted by time
```

The SQL output by this is:

```
select `events`.*, `clients`.`firstname`, `clients`.`surname`, `notes`.`note` from `events`
inner join `clients` on `events`.`clientid` = `clients`.`id`
inner join `notes` on `events`.`clientid` = `notes`.`clientid`
and `notes`.`created_at` = (
select created_at from notes where clientid = clients.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)
where `cancelled` = ? and `complete` = ? order by `eventtime` asc
```

The query works perfectly, but has gotten really slow as the table has grown in size. It takes around 30 seconds to complete, and is the only query running this slowly.

Is there a better way to organise the joins? Would it make sense to get the most recent note in a separate query?

Many thanks,

Sam

Comment: Database query optimization questions might be better suited for the [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Do an `EXPLAIN select events.*,...` and show us the output

Comment: add indexes to all fields that used in join and where conditions

Comment: show us the indexes and cardinality as well as the explain plan

Comment: Don't know how to produce an explain from Laravel at this stage. Any ideas and will gladly post anything.

Comment: Adding indexes as per the answer below and using the MAX SQL statement from the other answer dramatically cut the query time from 30seconds to 1.8ms. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These indexes would be helpful

1. `events(clientid)`
2. `clients(id)`
3. `notes(clientid,created_at)`
4. `notes(created_at,clientid)`

Note, 4 could be
`notes(created_at,clientid,cacelled,complete,eventtime)` and I would not add note to it, making it a covering index, because note would be too wide.

Comment: Wow, just adding indexes 1, 2 and 3 cut the query time from 30 seconds to 3.8ms. Works perfectly now, thank you.

Comment: In re-looking at your query, 4 would not be helpful, but tacking on `cancelled, complete, eventtime` to 3 could help. Sorry, still waking up here

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you can try below query as by it you can avoid reverse ordering for notes table in subquery if it is a bulky table-

```
SELECT `events`.*, `clients`.`firstname`, `clients`.`surname`, `notes`.`note` 
FROM `events` 
INNER JOIN `clients` ON `events`.`clientid` = `clients`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `notes` ON `events`.`clientid` = `notes`.`clientid` 
AND `notes`.`created_at` = 
(
SELECT MAX(created_at) 
FROM notes 
WHERE clientid = clients.id
) 
WHERE `cancelled` = ? AND `complete` = ? 
ORDER BY `eventtime` ASC
```

Assuming there will be index on all joined fields and also on created_at field.

Also if events table contains some text/blob or long varchar type columns then you should exclude them if not required as you are using events.*

Comment: why not to do like: `notes`.`id` = 
(
SELECT MAX(id) 
FROM notes 
WHERE clientid = clients.id
)    if You do no edit created_at field manually the id and created_at both will indicate latest record. Primary keys are always fast and because id is integer type it takes less CPU time for operation

Comment: Using @num8er and the original suggesting about halved the query time. Very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solution steps:

1. change Your query

thats your query:

```
select `events`.*, `clients`.`firstname`, `clients`.`surname`, `notes`.`note` from `events`
inner join `clients` on `events`.`clientid` = `clients`.`id`
inner join `notes` on `events`.`clientid` = `notes`.`clientid`
and `notes`.`created_at` = (
select created_at from notes where clientid = clients.id ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1)
where `cancelled` = ? and `complete` = ? order by `eventtime` asc
```

lets change it like so:

```
select `events`.*, `clients`.`firstname`, `clients`.`surname`, `notes`.`note` from `events`
inner join `clients` on `events`.`clientid` = `clients`.`id`
inner join `notes` on `events`.`clientid` = `notes`.`clientid`
and `notes`.`id` = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM notes WHERE clientid = clients.id)
where `cancelled` = ? and `complete` = ? order by `eventtime` asc
```

if You want to get latest record from notes there is no need to sort by created_at and get latest one. if You do not edit tables manually so MAX(id) and latest created_at both will indicate latest record.

2. add indexes

indexes always help to database to avoid fetching whole table in search of data. 
so when You join or do queries it collects in memory all records that has relative field condition and then joins the arrays of data. 
adding indexes will help database first off all quickly find data that needed.
indexes helps to database engine go to offset in binary file where the needle data exists

so lets add indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `events` ADD INDEX `clientid` (`clientid`);
ALTER TABLE `notes` ADD INDEX `clientid` (`clientid`);
ALTER TABLE `events` ADD INDEX `cancelled` (`cancelled`);
ALTER TABLE `events` ADD INDEX `complete` (`complete`);
ALTER TABLE `events` ADD INDEX `cancelled_complete` (`cancelled`, `cancelled`);
ALTER TABLE `events` ADD INDEX `eventtime` (`eventtime`);
```

That's all (:

p.s. main problem of most laravel developers is they forgot to set indexes when they write migration schemas. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#creating-indexes

Comment: several of these indexes would never be used with or without Laravel. In fact probably only the first two at best. So it would just bog down inserts/updates

Comment: I know about it, but because of complex queries might happen in future with this app and with author - best way is setting these indexes before (:

Comment: Not a good practice in the face of not even seeing other queries

Comment: ok, clientid is used in join - right? then when use where cancelled=0 and complete = 0  the indexes of 2 fields will not be helpfull? also combined index `cancelled_complete` (`cancelled`, `cancelled`) will help database not to check 2 indexes separately, but check 1 index in search of '0-0'. also adding index to eventtime is helpfull to do sorting because it will take top-most element from eventtime index. in big systems there is analytics queries that will happen. so additional indexes always needed.

Comment: that is not how mysql indexes work. The don't jump from one index to another like acrobats :> I understand your thinking though, and just like you said in your Answer, but in this case, people new to indexing do this. They make un-used indexes

Comment: (:  when You query like complete = 0  db engine looks in index to get offsets to where look for in binary data, isn't it?

Comment: samiles, can You do EXPLAIN query  to see what indexes are using? we want to look at

Comment: if you query on complete=0 (**and that is it**), yes, it uses an index on complete if the statistics are there, and there are enough rows. But he is not querying on complete=0 (note the **bold** above)

Comment: yes, he is doing `cancelled` = ? and `complete` = ?   so it's using index that keeps combination of these 2 fields.

Comment: so you didn't read the bold. Because you just said this and that. I need to move on.

Comment: ok. no prob (: at least Your answer was helpful for him. thanks

Comment: my comments will be helpful for you someday too. You might note, about all I answer is `mysql` tag stuff. Kinda know it, but my text ain't gospel

Comment: @Drew, of course these discussion is necessary. I always experimenting with indexes and query plan to get best combinations. Thank You (: